# Returning an array from a function declared with decltype(auto)?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20, return-type, decltype

I would like to return an array (or reference to an array) from a function as follows:

```
decltype(auto) bar() { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

Unfortunately, it results in very cryptic errors. GCC complains:

```
error: cannot convert 'int [2]' to 'int [2]' in return
```

and Clang is not better in explaining the problem:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ao7Txa9oP

Is it even possible to return an array from a function? (I am fine with getting rid of `decltype(auto)`.)

If it is not, then why, provided that functions can accept arrays in various ways, e.g.:

```
void f(auto [2]);
void f(auto (&)[2]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indeed `decltype(auto)`. The return type is deduced by following this list (the expression in question is the one given to the return statement):

> **[dcl.type.decltype]** (redacted for emphasis)
>
> ```
> decltype-specifier:
>     decltype ( expression )
> ```
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.type.decltype#1) For an expression E, the type denoted by decltype(E) is defined
> as follows:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access ([expr.ref]), decltype(E) is the
>   type of the entity named by E. If there is no such entity, or if E
>   names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - ...
> - ...

The type of `a` is `int[2]`. So you are essentially defining a function with an array return type... but...

> **[dcl.fct]**
>
> [11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#11) Functions shall not have a return type of type array or
> function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or
> reference to such things. There shall be no arrays of functions,
> although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

You produced an ill-formed function type inadvertently. So yes the solution, as you noted, is to not use `decltype`. You can explicitly return a reference (to a deduced array type), since this is really what you want:

```
auto& bar() { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

or if you want to be explicit about the return type, without entering declarator hell, you can specify it in a trailing fashion:

```
auto bar() -> int(&)[2] { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

Either way, I'd say it's better than relying on the (at times cryptic) semantics of `decltype`. There are no subtle bugs when you explicitly return an lvalue reference (when that is your entire intention).

---

As an aside, your last question contains declarations that are not specified as legal *yet* (though accepted by implementations since it is pretty much agreed they should be). This is [CWG Issue 2397](https://wg21.link/cwg2397). But the gist of it is that it behaves as one would expect an array type in a function parameter. `auto [2]` is adjusted to `auto*`, while `auto(&) [2]` only binds to arrays of specific type. This is meant to be an abbreviated function template, equivalent to:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T[2]);

template<typename T>
void f(T(&)[2]);
```

Return types are simply not adjusted like parameters are. Where parameter type adjustment itself is a C heritage thing, from which we got raw arrays that are not first-class citizens. They are pretty irregular as types go. If you need "saner" value-semantics with arrays, you have `std::array` for this purpose exactly.

Comment: Hmm `return (a);`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - No. I would not give what is imo bad advice just to flash my C++ knowledge. `auto &` is a reference, and it  contains far less pitfalls to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
decltype(auto) bar() { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

The return type would be deduced as the type of `a` by [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), i.e. an array type as `int[2]`, which can't be specified as the return type of function.

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the type of the *entity* named by this expression.

If you want to return a pointer as `int*`, you can

```
auto bar() { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

If you want to return a reference to array as `int(&)[2]`, you can

```
auto& bar() { static int a[2]; return a; }
```

Or

```
decltype(auto) bar() { static int a[2]; return (a); }
//                                             ^ ^
// for lvalue expression decltype yields T&; i.e. int(&)[2]
```

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are often different types.